# How to sort entire dataframe by one row's content

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
   Col1       Col2      Col3        Col4       Col5

 1794.7809  336.5778  0.2233495   0.53030000  5594.83998270378
  28.7967   16.0021   2.6449000    81.8828        g
  31.6036   11.7235   2.5185000   0.53030000      g
 162.0520  136.0310   4.0612000   0.03740000      g
 23.8172   9.5728     2.3385000   0.61470000      g
```

I would like to sort the entire dataframe based on the values in the first row (namely : 1794.7809  336.5778  0.2233495   0.53030000  5594.83998270378)   such that not only this row is sorted but all rows corresponding to these values are also arranged properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
The output should be as follows:

```
   Col3       Col4                 Col2      Col1            Col5

 0.2233495    0.53030000        336.5778   1794.7809     5594.83998270378
  2.6449000   81.8828          16.0021     28.7967           g
  2.5185000   0.53030000        11.7235   31.6036          g
 4.0612000    0.03740000        136.0310    162.0520        g
 2.3385000     0.61470000        9.5728    23.8172          g
```

(Note : Search on google for this issue was fruitless)
(Note : Part of an assignment)
Regards

Comment: @StevenBeaupré no, it doesn't work.

Comment: The only thing you are missing here is a logic. Why would you sort a data frames based on the rows? What is the benefit of doing that?  Have you gone through this paper by Hadley Wickham http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf ?

Comment: You need to understand why a dataframe is defined properly with columns and rows, there is a grammar for defining variables and observations. From the type of sorting you want, you are completely ignoring the grammar. What purpose would that serve?

Comment: @Pj_ I understand what you are saying, but like I said, it's part of a data mining assignment. So currently I'm trying to select the column with the max value in the first row, add it to a new dataframe and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is no factor variable in your original data frame, you can use order on the first row, which

> returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into
>   ascending or descending order

and apply the result on the data frame:

```
df[order(as.numeric(unlist(df[1,])))]

#        Col3    Col4     Col2      Col1             Col5
# 1 0.2233495  0.5303 336.5778 1794.7809 5594.83998270378
# 2 2.6449000 81.8828  16.0021   28.7967                g
# 3 2.5185000  0.5303  11.7235   31.6036                g
# 4 4.0612000  0.0374 136.0310  162.0520                g
# 5 2.3385000  0.6147   9.5728   23.8172                g
```

Converting factor variable to character should be fairly straight forward with the `mutate_if` function from `dplyr`:

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. do not understand why the question was voted down though.

Comment: @SiddharthSharma Probably because many misunderstood what you were asking in the first place. Had this _"I'm trying to select the column with the max value in the first row, add it to a new dataframe and so on."_  been there in the main body, it would've been much more clear to many.

Comment: @Pj_ Alright. I'll try to improve my future questions. Thanks for the advice. :)